# Ограничить поиск яндекс карта API?

Tags: javascript, html, yandex-maps-api

подскажите как в Яндекс карте API ограничить поиск, т.е как сделать поиск только по одному городу или области, а не по все России, я хочу что бы когда пользователь вводил данные в поля адрес, автоподсказки были только одного города, а сейчас например: Ленина 1 и он выводит разные города[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Средствами API можно задать прямоугольную область поиска, примерно соответствующую по координатам нужному городу / области с помощью boundedBy: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/geocode-docpage/#geocode__param-options.boundedBy